# Can $_COOKIE ever contain cookies set by another domain?

Tags: php, cookies

Suppose I have a website www.mysite.com.

Can the `$_COOKIE` array ever contain cookies that were set by domains other than `www.mysite.com`, if I am using `$_COOKIE` via PHP code on the domain `www.mysite.com`?

My understanding (which is quite limited!) is that a domain can only access cookies that it set itself, which means that `$_COOKIE` could only contain cookies which were set by the domain. Is this correct?

Comment: It would be a severe security issue otherwise

Comment: Yeah If it was then people could stole each other cookies. And we should have a WAR. Like hackers stealing facebook cookies or stackoverflow cookies easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Only a nonfunctional browser would do such a thing.

Only the client can view all the cookies for all separate domains, the browser makes sure to send only the cookies related to the current domain and non other.

Comment: At first, the word `No` is confusing.

Comment: When I said no, I was responding to his original question: Can the $_COOKIE array ever contain cookies that were set by domains other than www.mysite.com?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I accepted this one just because it was the first by a few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly, `$_COOKIE` has only access to cookies setted by his domain.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but only for subdomains to share some cookies, by using '.domain.com' instead 'domain.com' .

Across different domains, like domain1.com and domain2.com is not possible.

Comment: How about seeting for `.com`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that's an interesting thought, I have not heard of this before, but if the browser allows it I think it would be considered a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `http request` sent to your server from browser will contain the cookies that you have placed in the browser. Accessing a cookie that does not belong to your domain will be a malicious activity, giving rise to security issues.

- **cookie stealing/session hijacking** is a type of attack that is used to steal an active session of another user.
- After a user logs in to a website, a cookie is stored on the computer so that every time he goes to a different page on that site, re-authentication is not needed.
- If someone gets a hold of someone else's cookies and add them in the browser, then attacker's stored username/password combo or session ID becomes the same as victim's, therefore authenticating the attacker on a website as someone else (the victim), without having to know their credentials.